# How can I do a complex substitution that using javascript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my web pages I have source that looks like this:

```
<div id="opt_3"  >A)</div>
<div id="opt_2"  >B)</div>
<div id="opt_4"  >C)</div>
<div id="opt_5"  >D)</div>
<div id="opt_1"  >E)</div>
```

What I need is to create a javascript that when running takes something like this as an input var:

```
Text 1 word word word this is a text 3 word word.
```

and changes it to

```
<strong>E</strong> word word word this is a <strong>A</strong> word word.
```

or

```
abc text 4 word
```

and changes it to

```
abc <strong>C</strong> word
```

The job of my javascript will be to taken the number inside of the string "Text X" or "text X", look at the first character of the id field that matches the value of X and substitute that character for "Text X".

I have jQuery loaded. Can that help by giving me some suggestioins? Do I need to use javascript as well as jQuery?

Can someone give me some advice on how I could do this. I am not very familiar with javascript or with jQuery.

Comment: It is not an answer, just a comment: JQuery is a library written in Javascript. So, if you're using JQuery, you're using Javascript.

Comment: @Jason - Thanks for the comment. Yes maybe my question was not worded very well. Ideally I would like to everything in jQuery but I think that's too much for ask even though jQuery seems like it can do a lot.

Comment: As Fatih suggested may be, if you can, you should use something else than "Text X". For instance a <span> tag. Then, it will very easy to select and change the style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you will need jQuery

```
//get the original text
txt = $('#text-container').text();
//split the whole text by the words "Text"
// this way each string in the array arr will contain as its first member the number 
// without the splitting text
arr = txt.split('Text');
answerText = '';
for(i=0; i < arr.size(); i++){
    words=arr[i].split(' '); //split by spaces
    //the first word will be the number
    nr = words[0];
    //then we look up the corresponding option, and substitute the number
    words[0] = $('#opt_'+nr).text();
    //and rebuild the original text
    answerText += words.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should this

```
var myText = 'Lorem {0} Dolor {1} Amet is a {2} text.';

var textReplace = function(txt) {
    for (var i = 0, ii = arguments.length - 1; i < ii; i++) {
        txt = txt.replace('{' + i + '}', arguments[i + 1]);
    }
    return txt;
}

textReplace(myText, 'ipsum', 'sit', 'dummy');
```

This function requires arguments. The first one is the text that you want to replace in a way. Other arguments will be replaced in your text. I suggest you to use wrapper texts with curly braces instead Text 4 or whatever.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you faith. I agree maybe it is easier to use {1} etc. I think your code would work but I am not sure how to populate the arguements of textReplace. This will depend on the values of the data in the fields id="opt_3".

Comment: But isn't there already a [jQuery plugin](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) or method for this exact thing?

Comment: @mplungjan, forget about doing everything with a jQuery plugin. This is not a good way.

Comment: Of course it is if jQuery is already in the page and the method is available (which it will be I think).

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do exactly as you describe:

```
var input = "Text 1 word word word this is a text 3 word word.";
input = input.toLowerCase();
var split = input.split(" ");
for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if(split[i].toLowerCase() == "text") {
         var num = split[i+1];
         var val = $("#opt_" + num).text();
         input = input.replace("text " + num, "<strong>" + val + "</strong>");
    }  
}
alert(input);
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/mh9Mf/2/). It splits your string on spaces, then loops through the resulting array, looking for occurences of the word "text". When it finds one, it replaces that word and the next word (which will be a number according to your instructions) with the value of the corresponding element, wrapped in `strong` tags.

Comment: @Alex - Thanks, missed that bit :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a case-insensitive RegExp replace with a callback function, like this:

```
function textReplace(v){
    return v.replace(/text ([0-9])/gi,function(i,e){
        return "<strong>"+$("#opt_"+e).text().substring(0,1)+"</strong>";
    });
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/pLpxN/